# Is it possible to use Rails and HTML Framework iUI together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, iui

I'm having some difficulties getting IUI and Rails to place nicely together. Rails wants to override iUI with its voodoo. Any way to get them to place nicely?

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem but last update is from 2008, it might be outdated...

https://github.com/noelrappin/rails-iui

Answer (score 0):

I have just made used iUI with rails without the gem and without problems, but you should also consider [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com).